# Accessing remote java file (.jar) from php

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I followed following [phpjavaBridge](https://phpcoderblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/php-java-run-java-from-php-tutorial-how-to-run-java-code-from-php-use-java-in-php-java-php-php-to-java-tutorial/comment-page-1/#comment-760)
 to communicate from php to java, working fine if .jar(java program is running on local host (if both php and java are on same machine)). But  my requirement is that java file is running on different machine and php on other, how should I communicate them,
Let me explain, what I am doing, Request is send from web page(php) to a java program (would be running on remote machine) through php/java Bridge to perform a task, some parameters are passed from php to java, after completing task, java program return's back some parameters to php, this is working fine if java program and  web are on same machine,but I want to run java file on other machine

Comment: java program is in form of .jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `deployJava.js` to run .jar file in php.

**What actually deployJava.js do?** : deployJava.js will run your .jar file in php as applet. You can run .jar file in php or html using applet. deployJava.js will help you to pass parameters in .jar file and retrieve events returned from java program.

I have used to run remote .jar file as applet in html file using deployJava.js.

Example Code Snippet :

```
<script src="deployJava.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attributes = { id:'peers', code:'net.sourceforge.peers.javascript.JsUserAgent',  width:1, height:1} ;
    var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'applet-tests.jnlp'} ;
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited answers with example code snippet. FYI. @AbdulGhaffar

Comment: Still confused, how should I do this, I have edited my Question, Please have a look on that.

Comment: you want to run java file or .jar file? Because both will be run in different way. @AbdulGhaffar or if possible plz explain in more detail with some code snippet.

Comment: .jar file(I created .jar of my java program)